# Using R's Digest Package to Sign an HTTP request to Amazon Dynamodb's API

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I trying to use Rs Digest package to create a signature for Amazon's API for Dynamodb.   The signature requires sha256.  Currently, I am testing R's digest package to see if its yield the correct output, given my input.

According to the Amazon website example, if my input is:

Input:   `"iam"`

then my output should be:

Targeted Output:  `'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'`

When I use the following R command:

```
digest("iam", algo="sha256", serialize=FALSE)
```

I get the following output:

```
"d457e3a99392a03f47057f50ac1cbc5d0365131575477971bf85177a0c0fed22"
```

I've tried various input combinations (setting serialize=TRUE, etc.) but have not had any luck.

**Update**

Per Rohit's response, I updated my R function and approach but I'm still not getting the correct Sample Signature.  Here are my steps:

1. Based on Amazon [Calculate AWS Signature Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html)
2. Now using the following R formula/script:

hmac(hmac(hmac(hmac("AWS4wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY","20110909", "sha256", serialize=FALSE, raw=FALSE),"us-east-1", "sha256", serialize=FALSE, raw=FALSE),"iam", "sha256", serialize=FALSE, raw=FALSE),"aws4_request", "sha256", serialize=TRUE, raw=TRUE)

3. Getting this result:

   fe bd 15 b6 ac 8d 68 7a 93 f9 1c 9c dc 9e f8 d9 f1 79 fb a8 62 71 14 98 3a 35 0c 09 a0 ea 2e f5

that does not match the Sample Signature in the Amazon example:

```
152 241 216 137 254 196 244 66 26 220 82 43 171 12 225 248 46 105 41 194 98 237 21 229 169 76 144 239 209 227 176 231
```

I tried changing parameters on my R function, but just can't seem to match the Amazon example. If anyone has some experience with this or seems something I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate your input.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two places where the problem lies.

Firstly, the AWS v4 Signature is an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) using the AWS secret key as a secret (among other things). The HMAC process uses a cryptographic hash like MD5 or SHA256, but it not just a hash of a single piece of data (`"iam"` in your case) - it also needs a 'secret'. I guess you would be more interested in the [hmac](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/digest/docs/hmac) function in R - it can use SHA256 as an 'algo'.

Secondly, if you look at the [Java example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html) of how a signature is calculated and the expected values:

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception  {
    String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception  {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] kDate    = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion  = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}
```

Expected Values

```
kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

You see that the `kService` is calculated using `kRegion`, which calculated using `kDate`, which itself is calculated using the AWS secret key. So you would have to do something similar to calculate the signature.